# Free webmail server application to monitor multiple IMAP accounts

Tags: gratis, web-apps, email-client, self-hosted, imap

I'm looking for a free webmail application that runs on a web server with support for multiple IMAP accounts. The webmail solutions I found out there like [WebmailLite](http://www.afterlogic.org/webmail-lite) and [Roundcube](https://roundcube.net/) don't offer multiple IMAP accounts support.

My goal is to manage multiple IMAP accounts I own from a single application, something like desktop applications such as Thunderbird and Mail.app do, but I'm looking for something I can host on my web server.

Ideally this webmail software is written in PHP, but any server side language like Node.js, Ruby and Python would work as well.

Comment: Thanks @Izzy, I added the "free" price tag. :) I also really like Roundcube, and I recently found out that Webmail has a paid version with multiple IMAP accounts support: http://www.afterlogic.com/webmail-client  . Unfortunately they charge per mailbox.

Comment: Great – so time for comment-cleanup now. If you find a plugin to do that with Roundcube, please make sure to ping me in chat! For now, I can only see a work-around: Share all your folders amongst the accounts, and use the addresses as "multiple identities". Not a clean solution, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OwnCloud has a plugin called [Mail](https://github.com/owncloud/mail) which provides a web-interface to multiple IMAP accounts.

It's far from perfect in its current state (issues with formatting when replying/forwarding), and it locks you into OwnCloud infrastructure (attachments should be uploaded via OwnCloud Files app, etc.) I'm using it myself, but wouldn't mind switching to a better solution if I find one, so I'm starring this question in hope it will get more answers.

Answer (score 1):

[MailPile](https://www.mailpile.is/) is an e-mail client. It's web-based; though primarily intended for localhost use, it can also be used as (self-hosted) webmail interface.

From their [FAQ](https://www.mailpile.is/faq/#tec-7):

> **Will Mailpile support multiple email accounts?**
>
> Yes, you can use more than one e-mail account at once with Mailpile, both to receive mail and send.
>
> **I run a server! Can I can use Mailpile to give my users webmail access?**
>
> Note that Mailpile is primarily written as a personal application, it is not designed for large multi-user installations.
>
> That said, this should become possible for small groups quite soon after our 1.0 release. Mostly we will need to document the recommended setup procedure.

Also, it's free and gratis [open source](https://github.com/mailpile/Mailpile).

Answer (score 1):

[AfterLogic Webmail Lite](http://www.afterlogic.org/webmail-lite) allows you to set up multiple identities in a single login, so you can see mail from multiple sources.

It's php based and free. In fact we chose it over RoundCubeMail, and SquirrelMail and some others after review.

It's very quick as well, but unfortunately you need the paid version for mobile / phone browser support.